# Partial regression plot for multiple regression - residual analysis

Tags: regression, least-squares

For the most part, the residuals seem normally distributed and linear model seems appropriate for the data that I am trying to fit. However, for one independent variable, they don't look normal and seem to follow a trend causing Heteroscedasticity concern.

```
model = sm.formula.ols(formula="gdp_change ~ govt_effectiveness * complexity + democracy + income + labor", data=df6).fit()
```

print(model.summary)

[image]

```
# Residual plots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
fig = sm.graphics.plot_partregress_grid(model, fig=fig)
```

How do I interpret that variable? Does it need to be transformed? Are there outliers? problems with linearity?

Comment: what term are you circling? is it the interaction term? can you provide more details

Comment: It's not a interaction term. It's income per capita for each country in the sample.